# Approximate representation of functions using Dirac delta

Tags: functions, numerical-methods, dirac-delta

I have seen some physics books giving an approximate representation, $f_{\text{appx}}(x)$, of a function $f(x)$ where,

$$f_{\text{appx}}(x) =\sum_{n=1}^{N} \alpha_n \delta(x-x_n)$$

and

$$\alpha_n = \int_{\infty}^{} f(x)\delta(x-x_n)\, dx=f(x_n)$$

which appears to me that the Dirac delta, $\delta(x-x_n)$, is being used as the basis functions. I have a few questions regarding this.

1. Wouldn't the summation $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \alpha_n \delta(x-x_n)$ become $+\infty$ when $x=x_n$?.
2. The approximated function $f_{\text{appx}}(x) $ doesn't seem to be square integrable and the norm of the error i.e. $\left \| f(x)-f_{\text{appx}}(x) \right \|$ would be infinite. In this case how is the approximation valid?.

Comment: I think the problem is 'physics books'. I would hazard the passage is presenting some kind of heuristic rather than a proof. The appropriate mathematical context for the Dirac delta is either measure theory, or distributions.

Comment: In physics it can represent the charge density of a set of charged particles. A particle is an idealization in classical electromagnetic theory: It occupies a CERO volume !!! such that its density $\to \infty$ which is a real source of problems. Indeed, it poses some mathematical problems in such context. It has been studied extensively for many years (starting with Max Abraham in 1902) . A friend of mine who is in the mathematical physics area considers this problem in his PhD Thesis.  I'll ask him for a reference. Indeed, classical electromagnetic sources must be considered as a fluid.

Answer (score 2):

In looking at Griffiths' book *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics*, 1st Ed., p. 52-53, he talks about the fact that scattering states aren't normalizable; perhaps your physics book is talking about scattering states?

Perhaps more relevantly, on pages 101 and 102 of the same, Griffiths uses the delta functions as a basis because they are the eigenfunctions of the position operator, and they're complete. He has the following footnotes on page 102 that might clarify for you what's going on:

> 21 We are engaged here in a dangerous stretching of the rules, pioneered by Dirac (who had a kind of inspired confidence that he could get away with it) and disparaged by von Neumann (who was more sensitive to mathematical niceties), in their rival classics (P. A. M. Dirac, *The Principles of Quantum Mechanics*, first published in 1930, 4th Ed., Oxford (Clarendon Press) 1958, and J. von Neumann, *The Mathematical Foundations of Quantum Mechanics*, first published in 1932, revised by Princeton Univ. Press, 1955). **Dirac notation** invites us to apply the language and methods of linear algebra to functions that lie in the "almost normalizable" suburbs of Hilbert space. It turns out to be powerful and effective beyond any reasonable expectation.
>
> 22 That's right: We're going to use, as bases, sets of functions none of which is actually in the space! They may not be normalizable, but they *are* complete, and that's all we need.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to imagine that any distribution can be represented in the form
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty f(x_n) \delta(x - x_n),
$$
where
$$
\bigcup_{n = 1}^\infty x_n = {\rm supp}(f).
$$
Indeed, if the support of $f$ is represented in that form, then for any compactly supported $\varphi$ with ${\rm supp}(\varphi) \subseteq {\rm supp}(f)$, we have
$$
(f, \varphi) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \varphi(x) dx = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty f(x_n) \varphi(x_n).
$$
In this context, the function
$$
f_{\rm appx}(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^N f(x_n) \delta(x - x_n)
$$
is the partial sum of $f$, thus $f$ can be approximated by $f_{\rm appx}$.

Regarding your questions. From mathematics point of view, the answer to your first question is- no. You have to treat the representation of $f_{\rm appx}$ in the sense of distributions, i.e., for the above function $\varphi$,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{\rm appx}(x) \varphi(x) dx = \sum_{n = 1}^N \alpha_n \varphi(x_n) = \sum_{n = 1}^N f(x_n) \varphi(x_n),
$$
which is a partial sum of $(f, \varphi)$.

Since you deal with distributions and not proper functions, instead of $|| f - f_{\rm appx} ||$, you should consider the norm (e.g., in $l^p$)
$$
|| (f, \varphi) - (f_{\rm appx}, \varphi) || = \left|\left| \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \varphi(x) dx - \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{\rm appx}(x) \varphi(x) dx \right|\right| = \left|\left| \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \varphi(x) dx - \sum_{n = 1}^N f(x_n) \varphi(x_n) \right|\right| = \left|\left| \sum_{n = N}^\infty f(x_n) \varphi(x_n) \right|\right|.
$$
As you see, this norm can be quite large if you consider small values for $N$.

I would recommend you the useful book by Teodorescu, Kecs and Toma "Distribution Theory: With Applications in Engineering and Physics", where the usage of distributions in physics and mechanics is mathematically justified.