# Finding an orthonormal basis of the subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, gram-schmidt

> Find an orthonormal basis of the subspace:
>   $$V = {[x, y, z, w]^T:x+y+z+w=0}$$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$

First I found a $4\times4$ determinant to verify whether they are non-singular or not.
$$\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{vmatrix}=1\ne0$$

Then to orthogonalize the basis I applied Gram-Schmidt process,
$$v_1=x_1=(1,1,1,1)$$

Is my basis $(1,1,1,1)$ correct?

Comment: "*Is my basis $(1,1,1,1)$ correct?*"  As a basis for the space $V$, the set of vectors from $\Bbb R^4$ such that the sum of the entries is equal to zero?  No.  $(1,1,1,1)$ does not have sum of entries equal to zero, it has sum of entries equal to *four* and so is not even an element of the space, much less a basis for it.

Comment: @JMoravitz I followed Problem $3$ [HERE](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~yvorobet/MATH304-2011C/Lect3-12web.pdf)

Comment: @JMoravitz: It's actually possible, in rare cases, to use as bases, vectors, none of which are in the subspace. I don't think that's happening here - you probably have to have infinite dimensions to make it work. In any case, another reason $(1,1,1,1)$ cannot be a basis is that the dimension of $V$ is $3$, and you only have one vector.

Comment: @philip Problem $3$ is computing a basis of the orthogonal complement, $V^{\bot}$, of $V$. Is that what you want? If that is what is really wanted, then your answer is correct.

Comment: @philip The question in the linked slides is not the same question as this one by a wide margin.  The one in the linked slides asks you to find an orthonormal basis to the space spanned by $(1,1,1,1)$ and $(1,0,3,0)$.  That is a very different space than the space subject to the condition that $x+y+z+w=0$.

Comment: @philip An orthogonal basis of a vector space is just a basis of the same space in which any pair of two of its vectors are perpendicular.

Comment: You should first focus on finding a basis for the space you are actually being asked about.  Ignore Gram-Schmidt for now.  Finding a basis for the space itself ignoring orthonormality should have been covered in the previous chapter or the one before even that.  The condition $x+y+z+w=0$, if you let $y,z,w$ be free variables equal to $r,s,t$ respectively becomes $\begin{cases} x=-r-s-t\\y=r\\z=s\\w=t\end{cases}$, can you continue from there?

Comment: @AdrianKeister "*It's actually possible to use as bases, vectors, none of which are in the subspace*" Suppose that $v\notin V$ but $v\in\mathfrak{B}$ where $\mathfrak{B}$ is a basis for $V$.  Then among the finite linear combinations of elements of $\mathfrak{B}$ is $1\cdot v$ implying that $v$ should in fact be an element of $V$, a contradiction.  Of course every basis vector is itself going to be a vector of the space.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Your hidden assumption is that the basis itself has to be a subspace of $V,$ but that might not be necessary, depending on your goals. See my answer to this question, where I quote Griffiths, for a more complete (pun intended, of course) explanation: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2785471/approximate-representation-of-functions-using-dirac-delta/2785525#2785525.

Comment: @JMoravitz: Another way of looking at it is this: a basis means any vector in the space is a linear combination of vectors in the basis. That's not the same thing as saying that any linear combination of vectors in the basis is in the space.

Comment: @AdrianKeister What has any of this got to do with the finite-dimensional $\mathbb R^4$?

Comment: @AdrianKeister you seem to have a very strange definition of basis.  The definition I was taught and confirmed in various textbooks I have close at hand is "A basis B of a vector space V over a field F is a linearly independent subset of V that spans V."  You seem to have left out the condition that $B$ must be a subset of $V$.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I disagree with your proposed definition.  Using your definition, you could say things such as the space $V=\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3~:~y=z=0\}$ has $\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$ as a basis since every element of $V$ (*indeed, every element of $\Bbb R^3$ even*) can be represented as a linear combination of basis elements, ignoring the fact that the latter two are unnecessary.  $V$ in this example is clearly one-dimensional, and so only needs one basis element.

Comment: @JMoravitz: I think the situation only comes up in infinite-dimensional spaces. amd: It doesn't have anything to do with $\mathbb{R}^4$. Cheerfully admitted.

Comment: On the topic of bases of infinite dimensional spaces, [I recommend this primer](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~kesmith/infinite.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proposed basis vector is not in your subspace $$x+y+z+w=0$$ because $$1+1+1+1=4 \ne 0$$

you need to find some linearly  independent vectors in the subspace  to form a basis and then apply Gram-Schmidt method to find an orthonormal basis.

For example $$(1,-1,0,0), (0,1,-1,0), (0,0,1,-1)$$ are linearly independent vectors in your subspace.

Can you apply  Gram-Schmidt to that set to find an orthonormal basis?

Comment: Can I have different basis from what you have?

Comment: @philip of course.  Any vector space over an infinite field that is not zero dimensional has infinitely many valid bases for it.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you very much! Now I clearly understood.

Answer (score 0):

Note that ($1,1,1,1)$ is not a basis vector and that we need

- to find a basis for the subspace (the dimension is three then we need 3 basis vectors),
- apply GS process and finally normalize them.

Note that we can easily find by inspection

- $v_1=(1,0,-1,0)$
- $v_2=(0,1,0,-1)$

which are independent and orthogonal, then we need only a third vector to complete a basis. What about $v_3=(0,1,-1,0)$?

From here we need only to apply GS process to vector $v_3$ since $v_1$ and $v_3$ are given for free.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: That is a fine basis for the space, however it fails to be an orthogonal basis as well as it fails to be a normal basis.  Still, this is an important first step for the OP to understand.  Now that a basis has been found, what remains to be done is to orthonormalize the basis via Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: I still did not understand how you got those basis. Can you please explain.

Comment: @philip from setting $y,z,w$ as free variables equal to $r,s,t$ respectively, we get $\begin{cases}x=-r-s-t\\y=r\\z=~~s\\w=~~~~t\end{cases}$.  Rewritten with vectors: $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\w\end{bmatrix}=-r\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}-s\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}-t\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}$